Parameter estimation using L-BFGS
I'm reading through the paper from DeepMind on Training Compute-Optimal Large Language models and have a question on the transformation applied to the objective function.
The goal is to estimate $A, B, E, \alpha$ and $\beta$ in the below equation
$$\hat{L}(N, D) = E + \dfrac{A}{N^\alpha} + \dfrac{B}{D^\beta}$$
This is converted to the optimization problem to minimize
$\text{Huber}(\log \hat{L}(N, D) - \log L)$ which can be further expanded as
$\text{Huber}(\text{LogSumExp}(a - \alpha \log N, b - \beta \log D, e) - \log L)$ where $A, B, E = \exp(a), \exp(b), \exp(e)$.
The above optimization problem is solved using LBFGS.
Question:

Why the transformation $A, B, E = \exp(a), \exp(b), \exp(e)$ does not change the optimal solution. My hunch is that since exp is a monotonic function, the solution shouldn't change but is it allowed to do such transformations for each term in the summation

Why taking log of each of the terms in the summation does not change the optimal solution ?


